# How can I condense this code?

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-test

Here is part of a code I wrote:

```
Select[Subsets[Range[16]], 
   MemberQ[#, 2] && ! 
       ContainsAll[
         Level[Position[ζ[[All, 2]], 1], {2}]][#] ∨ 
     MemberQ[#, 3] && ! 
       ContainsAll[
         Level[Position[ζ[[All, 3]], 1], {2}]][#] ∨ 
     MemberQ[#, 4] && ! 
       ContainsAll[
         Level[Position[ζ[[All, 4]], 1], {2}]][#] ∨ 
     MemberQ[#, 5] && ! 
       ContainsAll[
         Level[Position[ζ[[All, 5]], 1], {2}]][#] ∨ 
     MemberQ[#, 6] && ! 
       ContainsAll[
         Level[Position[ζ[[All, 6]], 1], {2}]][#] ∨ 
     MemberQ[#, 7] && ! 
       ContainsAll[
         Level[Position[ζ[[All, 7]], 1], {2}]][#] ∨ 
     MemberQ[#, 8] && ! 
       ContainsAll[
         Level[Position[ζ[[All, 8]], 1], {2}]][#] ∨ 
     MemberQ[#, 9] && ! 
       ContainsAll[
         Level[Position[ζ[[All, 9]], 1], {2}]][#] ∨ 
     MemberQ[#, 10] && ! 
       ContainsAll[
         Level[Position[ζ[[All, 10]], 1], {2}]][#] ∨ 
     MemberQ[#, 11] && ! 
       ContainsAll[
         Level[Position[ζ[[All, 11]], 1], {2}]][#] ∨ 
     MemberQ[#, 12] && ! 
       ContainsAll[
         Level[Position[ζ[[All, 12]], 1], {2}]][#] ∨ 
     MemberQ[#, 13] && ! 
       ContainsAll[
         Level[Position[ζ[[All, 13]], 1], {2}]][#] ∨ 
     MemberQ[#, 14] && ! 
       ContainsAll[
         Level[Position[ζ[[All, 14]], 1], {2}]][#] ∨ 
     MemberQ[#, 15] && ! 
       ContainsAll[
         Level[Position[ζ[[All, 15]], 1], {2}]][#] ∨ 
     MemberQ[#, 16] && ! 
       ContainsAll[
         Level[Position[ζ[[All, 16]], 1], {2}]][#] &]];
```

Is there a way to condense all the "or" commands into a single line?

Comment: Could you add an explanation of your logic in words? What properties are you trying to express to retain some subsets?

Comment: Yes, Thank you.  Here $\zeta$ is a 16 X 16, {0,1} matrix representing a poset.  This part of the code gives me the (complement of ) order ideal of $\zeta$.  I just don't want to have to write essentially the same line multiple times when applying the code to various sizes of posets.

Comment: Sounds like one would use some sparse matrix arithmetric or `Graph`... A poset is basically a tree (or a forest), right? Unfortunately I do not have the time to find out what an order ideal is. Can you please explain that in short, non expert terms? And a concrete example for `ζ` to play with would be great.

Comment: I got the faint idea that `TopologicalSort[Graph[ζ]]` might bring you closer to the solution...

Comment: @geoffrey thank you for the explanation, but unfortunately that was completely over my head. What I meant was for you to tell us what properties of each subset you are targeting *in plain language*. Something like, it should contain *this* and have that other simple property, but not *that*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
nzp = SparseArray[Transpose @ ζ]["AdjacencyLists"];

selector1 = Function[x, Or @@
 (MemberQ[x, #] && Length[Complement[nzp[[#]], x]] >= 1 & /@ Range[2, 16])];

Select[Subsets[Range[16]], selector1]
```

Alternatively,

```
selector2 = Function[x,  Or @@ 
 (MemberQ[x, #] && ! ContainsAll[x, nzp[[#]]] & /@ Range[2, 16])];

Select[Subsets[Range[16]], selector2] == Select[Subsets[Range[16]], selector1]
```

> ```
> True
> ```